Assign role to resource in a different resource groups
I have a module that assigns the Azure Service Bus Sender role to the managed idenity for an app service.  I need to set the scope to the actual instance of the service bus, but it's not in the same resource group as the app service.
Here is my bicep:
param principalId string
param roleDefinitionID string
param serviceBusName string

resource serviceBus 'Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces@2022-10-01-preview' existing = {
  name: serviceBusName
}

resource azureServiceBusDataRoleDefinition 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions@2022-04-01' existing = {
  scope: subscription()
  name: roleDefinitionID
}

resource AzureServiceBusRoleAssignment 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments@2022-04-01' = {
  name: guid(subscription().id, principalId, roleDefinitionID)
  scope: serviceBus
  properties: {
    principalId: principalId
    roleDefinitionId: azureServiceBusDataRoleDefinition.id 
    principalType: 'ServicePrincipal' 
  }
}

The deployment is running against the resource group that holds to app service, so it can't find the service bus. Therefore, I call the above bicep as a module and set the scope to be the resource group containing the service bus.
module azureServiceBusSenderPremissions './azureServiceBus-roleassignment.bicep' = if (useAzureServiceBus){
  name: '${deployment().name}-bbb-${appServiceName}'
  scope: resourceGroup(serviceBusResourceGroup)
  params:{
    principalId: appServicesResource.identity.principalId
    roleDefinitionID: '69a216fc-b8fb-44d8-bc22-1f3c2cd27a39'
    serviceBusName: serviceBusName
  }
}

This doesn't work. It still tries to find the service bus under the wrong resource group.
I get this error:

The Resource 'Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/providers' under
resource group 'appservice-resourceGroup' was not found.


can you check the value of the serviceBusResourceGroup parameter ? It should work tbh

What is the exact error you are getting.

My variables were incorrect.  The resource group varaible was null.  Once I fixed that, it worked as is. Thanks for the help.

Your code looks good for assigning the Azure Service Bus Sender role to the managed identity for an app service existed in another resource group.
Try below steps to resolve the conflict and deploy it successfully:
As pointed by @Thomas, check that the service bus resource group parameter is accurate as the service bus resource existed.
Also try adding the  dependsOn block under the module configuration to avoid these kinds of conflicts as shown below.
Also provide a resource group name parameter separately in the module bicep code to allow the service bus where it is located without any misunderstanding.
After modifying it accordingly with the above slight changes, the deployment was working fine as expected.
module.bicep:
param useAzureServiceBus bool = true
param  serviceBusResourceGroup  string = 'caronew'
resource appServicesResource 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2024-04-01' existing = {
  name: appServiceName
}
module azureServiceBusSenderPremissions 'appser.bicep' = if (useAzureServiceBus){
  name: '${deployment().name}-bbb-${appServiceName}'
  scope: resourceGroup(serviceBusResourceGroup)
  params:{
    principalId: appServicesResource.identity.principalId
    roleDefinitionID: '69a216fc-b8fb-44d8-bc22-1f3c2cd27a39'
    serviceBusName: serviceBusName
  }
  dependsOn: [
    appServicesResource
  ]
}

param principalId string
param roleDefinitionID string = '69a216fc-b8fb-44d8-bc22-1f3c2cd27a39'
param serviceBusName string = 'servicebusA'

resource serviceBus 'Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces@2022-10-01-preview' existing = {
  name: serviceBusName
}

resource azureServiceBusDataRoleDefinition 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions@2022-04-01' existing = {
  scope: subscription()
  name: roleDefinitionID
}

resource AzureServiceBusRoleAssignment 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments@2022-04-01' = {
  name: guid(subscription().id, principalId, roleDefinitionID)
  scope: serviceBus
  properties: {
    principalId: principalId
    roleDefinitionId: azureServiceBusDataRoleDefinition.id 
    principalType: 'ServicePrincipal' 
  }
}

Deployment succeeded:



My variable were incorrect. The values were null.  Once I fixed that, it worked as is.
